# looping through html and deleting not found

Tags: javascript

So, i'm looping through the document body searching for all "#result>tbody>tr" objects. I'm then trying to search within those elements to see if any of the names exist, if they do, I would like to delete them. I got it working if I don't loop through the names and use a single object. If I try and loop through the names, it only loops four times and then nothing else happens.

Any ideas?

Edit: Currently there are 30 objects the first loop loops through. When I add the second loop into the mix to see if the sub-objects exist, it will only loop through four and than break the loop. Hope that explains better.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/8c9p7bp5/1/

```
var dlList = document.querySelectorAll("#result>tbody>tr");
for (var i = 0, len = dlList.length; i < len; i++) {

    var names = ['Test', 'Router', 'IP', 'Mod'];

    for (var j = 0, len = names.length; j < len; j++) {
        var vi = dlList[i].querySelector("td>br>img[title^='" + names[i] + "']");

        if(!dlList[i].contains(vi)) {
            //dlList[i].remove();
            console.log(dlList[i]);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I think you just need to change `names[i]` to `names[j]`

Comment: Oops, I did miss that, but this did not fix my issue. dlList has 30 objects but it will still only loop through the first four and then break.

Comment: Can you bring up a minimal verifiable example? Like on jsfiddle?

Comment: added an example to OP

Comment: Don't have time to figure out what the real issue is, but the reason it's only iterating 4 times is because you're redefining `len` to `names.length` which is 4. Changing your second `len` to something else, you'll see all the elements get deleted.

Answer (score 0):

First mistake of your code that you are using same limit for you nested loop "len", in the first iteration the value becomes 4 that's why it will break the parent loop.

Comment: Sorry, it will not break the loop but you code has the mistake mentioned above

Answer (score -1):

You initialize `j` but never use it in the inner loop.

Try this instead:

`var vi = dlList[i].querySelector("td>br>img[title^='" + names[j] + "']");`

Also, you should use a different variable than `len` for the inner loop to avoid running into variable scope issues.

Comment: Should be a comment, which is why I made this exact answer a comment :)

Comment: No, it's an answer to the question, and thus should be posted as an answer. Discussion on the differences between the two is here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17447/answer-or-comment-whats-the-etiquette

Comment: Where's your proof it's an `answer`? IMO, not enough information to have an answer. You just used my comment and made it one. The idea is to get the OP to try it in comment to see if it's the answer.

Comment: Thanks for downvoting me. We both answered 8 minutes ago - I didn't even see your comment until you pointed it out. Timestamps show our comments as 27 seconds apart. Downvotes should be for unhelpful and wrong answers, not because your ego was bruised or whatever other reason you justified to yourself.

Comment: Okay, I can give you benefit of the doubt. (I didn't downvote btw). But I still don't think this is the answer, since we don't have enough information, nor do we have any way to verify (OP should have included a minimal, verifiable example). Anyways, good luck.